# S3 to BigQuery Data Transfer Failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-transfer

BigQuery Data transfer from S3 (RDS Snapshot) sometimes fails with the below error.

```
2022-07-15T19:10:46.922686694ZJob bqts_62d1xxxx-0000-21xx-88xx-94eb2c0exxxx (table activity) failed with error UNAVAILABLE: Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.; JobID: 1040427xxxxxx:bqts_62d1xxxx-0000-21xx-88xx-94eb2c0exxxx
```

How can I prevent this? or setup retry when fails.

Comment: Is this an intermittent or frequent issue? If it is intermittent, I hope it will work once you retry it.

Comment: This happens once or twice a month, and I can retry manualy. However, it impacts subsequent processes and requries a lot of works for recovering. So, I'd like to know the root cause or, at least, how to retry automatically.

Comment: This issue will have to be looked into further. So, can you file an [issue](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) using this BigQuery issue tracker [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659). Note that there are no ETAs, but you can see all the updates there in the Issue Tracker which you have created.